# Significance of {n;s/...g;} in sed command

Tags: sed

I am trying to execute the following command:
  `sed -i.bak -e "/world/{n;s/hello/hi/g;}" check.txt`

content of check.txt :

```
 hello world  
 hello world  
hello at the last line world  
 hello world 1!!
```

Result received is :

```
 hello world  
 hi world  
hello at the last line world  
 hi world 1!!
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: Why are you running that particular command ? What is your goal ?

Answer (score 4):

The braces are just used to group commands, so the whole thing is:

```
/world/{ ... }      - on lines matching /world/, do the commands within {}
n                   - load next line (and print the current)
s/hello/hi/g        - substitute 'hi' for 'hello' on the _currently loaded_ line
```

i.e. it changed `hello` to `hi` on lines that come after lines with `world` (but doesn't check for `world` on those lines that get the substitution done.)